# Return slice from list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, slice, one-liner

What's the (one-line) syntax of returning a slice from list comprehension?
e.g.:

```
def foo(iterable):
    ls = [_ for _ in iterable]
    return ls[1:]
```

Comment: `list(iterable)` should be equivalent to your `for generator`. Lambdas are one liner alternatives to functions. But you could just do list(iterable)[1:]

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking... You seem to have your answer already.

Comment: Also note, your list comprehension is a bad choice in this specific case, `[x for x in whatever]`->`list(whatever)`

Comment: [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is the most generic solution to get a slice for any iterable.

Comment: NB: `foo` should really get `iterable` as argument.

Comment: Agree with previous comment.  `_` to Python programmers means "I can completely ignore this value", not "I'm too lazy to give it a name, but its value is important".  Use `x` or `i` or something.

Comment: `itertools.islice(iterator, 1, None)` removes the first element of an iterator.  Wrap it in a `list(...)` if you want the answer as a list, or just leave it as an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you simply slice the list comprehension?

```py
def foo(iterable):
    return [_ for _ in iterable][1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case you can just:

```
list(iterable)[2:]
```

but you also can:

```
[ i for i in range(10)][2:]

out[1] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

just some other tips, slicing from the end:

```
[ i for i in range(10)][-2:]

out[2] [8, 9]
```

conditional list comprehension:

```
[ i for i in range(10) if i%2==0]
out[3] [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```